# keep duplicates values by condition. Pandas

Tags: pandas, duplicates

i want to keep over duplicates values that are associates simultaneously with two specific values of other column only one of them.

Example:

```
id   | "A" | "B" | "C" | ... |

 0   | R1  |  0  |..

 1   | R1  |  1  |..

 2   | R1  |  2  |..

 3   | R1  |  4  |..

 4   | R2  |  1  |..

 5   | R2  |  3  |.. 

 6   | R3  |  0  |..

 7   | R3  |  2  |..

 8   | R3  |  3  |..

 9   | R4  |  1  |..

 10  | R4  |  2  |..

 11  | R4  |  3  |..
```

if duplicates in column "A" are associated to the values: 1 and 3 of column "B", then keep 3 :

```
id   | "A" | "B" | "C" | ... |

 0   | R1  |  0  |..

 1   | R1  |  1  |..

 2   | R1  |  2  |..

 3   | R1  |  4  |..

 5   | R2  |  3  |..

 6   | R3  |  0  |..

 7   | R3  |  2  |..

 8   | R3  |  3  |..

 10  | R4  |  2  |..

 11  | R4  |  3  |..
```

ergo...  i want to remove 3 on "B" if and only if duplicates in "A" have 1 and 3 on "B" (condition).

Comment: are they always in order or 3 can be before 1 for a duplicate, also will they always have just 2 values?

Comment: No, they aren't. And number 3 do not represent the max value of column "B" and the other value of the condition is not the min, it was an example, but those values refers to codes and don`t represent min or max of the column "B"

Comment: Of the duplicates in "A" I want to select those that have simultaneously two specific codes in "B" (for example 1 and 3) and keep only the row that has 3, assuming that "B" takes values ​​from 0 to 10

Comment: Did the below code work?

Comment: But i want to remove 3 on "B" if and only if duplicates in "A" have 1 and 3 on "B" (condition). In the example you've pass me if i add two new rows with R4 in "A" and 2 and 3 in "B", that sintax will remove 3 but the condition is not satisfacted